Evaluating $\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx$
I'm tring to find a primitive of  $$x \mapsto \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$$
I've tried methods like integration by parts but it seems the integral is non-elementary and likely involve the guassian error function. However I was not able to find a table containing the value of it.

Do you intend to evaluate a definite integral? I suspect there are problems near zero, if so.

Did you ask Wolfram Alpha or your favourite Computer Algebra system?

Take $a>0$.
$\begin{align*}
\int_a^x \frac{e^{-t^2}}{t^2} dt &= \left[ -\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t} dt\right]_a^x - \int_a^x -\frac{-te^{-t^2}}{t} dt\\
&= \frac{e^{-a^2}}{a} - \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\operatorname{erf} (a) - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\operatorname{erf} (x).
\end{align*}$
Now you want to get a nice constant so you should take as a primitive (for $x>0$):
$$F(x) = - \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}  - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\operatorname{erf} (x)$$
Which is not pretty but you can be sure you won’t get better since there is no way to get rid of the error function.

I think apart from the error function, you may also try Taylor series and keep its primitive in a form of power series.
Since we have
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
we get
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$
Therefore, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
   \int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2} &= \int \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}}{x^2}\\
                             &= \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2(n-1)}}{n!}\\
                             &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int (-1)^n \frac{x^{2(n-1)}}{n!}\\
                             &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{n!}
\end{aligned}$$
So we may also use $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{n!}$ as an answer.
